# Can't get alsamixer working although all config files look okay

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, equalizer, amixer

So, first of all, this is output of my aplay -l:

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I use the first card, so i change the configs:
asound.conf:

```
pcm.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
}

ctl.equal {
  type equal;
}

pcm.plugequal {
  type equal;
  slave.pcm "plughw:1,0";
}

pcm.!default {
  type plug;
  slave.pcm plugequal;
}
```

~/.asoundrc:

```
ctl.equal {
        type equal;
}

pcm.plugequal {
    type equal;
        slave.pcm "plughw:1,0";
}

pcm.equal{
    type plug;
    slave.pcm plugequal;
}
```

So as you see, devices are set as they should be,
but when i run alsamixergui -D equal, and put all the bars down
sound is still playing without change. If i run just alsamixer I can adjust
master audio properly. What could be the problem here?

Comment: As this is an english language site, and I don't do translation, please rerun your  `aplay` command as `env LANG=C aplay -l`

Comment: post edited @waltinator

Comment: The `equal` control device shows those controls that are implemented by the `equal` plugin. The default control device (which maps to `hw`) shows those controls that are implemented by the hardware.